# Hashmap comparison running time

Tags: java, comparison, hashmap, time-complexity

I am comparing 2 HashMaps, and I am trying to figure out the time complexity of the comparison loop.
The code is as follows:

```
//map1 is a HashMap and contains m elements and keys
//map2 is a HashMap and contains n elements and keys 
List<myObject> myList = new ArrayList<myObject>()  
for (String key: map1.keySet()){ 
    if(!map2.containsKey(key)){
        myList.add(map.get(key));
   }
 }
```

The first for loop will be **O(m)**. I found on some other forum that the containsKey() takes **lg(n)** time. Can someone please confirm that? I couldn't find it in the JavaDocs. 
If so , then the the total time complexity would be **O(mlg{n})**. 
Also any ideas on how to do this comparison in a better way would be helpful.

Comment: Here's the HashMap implementation: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on your hashcode algorithm and collisions.

Using a perfect hashcode, theoretically map look up is O(1), constant time, if there are collisions, it might be upto O(n).
So in your case, if you have good hash algorithms, it would be O(m).

if you look at [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), you can get more understanding about the concept. You can also look at Map source code.

Comment: Well I am using the default Java HashMap. Anywhere I could find the defaults for these?

Comment: presuming that java's default implmentation is OK for strings it should be average case constant time.

Comment: Yes I am using the default HashCode.

Comment: @DarthVader I was confused by what rgamber was saying, not what Kevin was saying

Answer (score 1):

The Java HashMap implementation should constantly be resizing the internal data structure to be larger than the number of elements in the map by a certain amount and the hashing algorithm is good so I would assume collisions are minimal and that you will get much closer to O(1) than O(n).

What HashMap are you using? The one that comes with Java? Your own?

Comment: I am using the default one that comes with Java.

Comment: Ok, well it's pretty damn good then. Have a look at the source: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html
Note, in particular, the resize method, the threshold member (the HashMap will resize as soon as the number of elements == capacity*load_factor). Default load_factor is 0.75. And table size grows by factor of 2 each time. Default initial capacity is 16.

Comment: i dont agree with you on this. size of the backing array or linked list doesnt affect the look up time. if your objects return same hashcode, map uses equals method and visits all of the collided ones for equality to find the matching one.

Comment: and load factor is a variable that determines the location of the item, but if you have collision, load factor doesnt do any good. look at chaining, probing..

Comment: Thanks, I will read into the information. So in my case the running time should be O(m) then..? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: @DarthVader: Yes, size of backing array relative to number of elements (load factor) does affect look-up time. Low load-factor means more misses and having to chain or probe more.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the time complexity of the outer loop: *O(n)*.  The asymptotic complexity of `HashMap.containsKey()` is *O(1)* unless you've done something ridiculous in your implementation of `myObject.hashCode()`.  So your method should run in *O(n)* time.  An optimization would be to ensure you're looping over the smaller of the two maps.

Note that `TreeMap.containsKey()` has *O(log n)* complexity, not `HashMap`...  Stop looking at those forums :)

Comment: Thanks. That's the reason I posted here, I was getting confused.!

Comment: Oh, by the way: `map1.keySet().retainAll(map2.keySet())`